# React error on rendering : Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i got this code in react

```
getDocuments: function(){
if(this.state.documents.length == 0){
  return(<div>Vous navez aucument document pour le moment</div>);
} else {
  var documentsData = this.state.documents.map(function(doc) {
    return (
      <Row md={12} key={doc.document_id}>
        <Col md={3} xs={4}>
          <label>Titre du document : {doc.title}</label>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3} xs={4}>
          <label>Ajouté le : {moment(doc.upload_date).format("L")}</label>
          <Form.Button type='button' onClick={  this.deleteDocument(doc.document_id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</Form.Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  });
  return documentsData;
```

Who is supposed to render HTML displaying some infos stored in my `this.state.documents` map. It worked pretty well before i add the `onClick` event on the `Form.Button`.

This is my deleteDocument function :

```
deleteDocument:function(doc_id){
    request.post('/documents/delete/'+this.props.requestID+'/'+doc_id).set('Accept', 'application/json').end(function(err, res) {
      if (res.body.result) {
        window.location.href = '/request/edit';
      } else {
        this.setState({'cannotUpdateRequest':true});
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

Which is simply supposed to make a request on a pre-defined route that'll handle the back end logic of deleting a document, but the console is giving me this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteDocument' of undefined`.
Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: You should set `this` for `.map`

Comment: Thanks alexander. Despite the research i made i havent found this !